# Visualization tool for database queries

Tags: open-source, javascript, database

I am developing a website to display Gamification information (velocity, value, and quality) using Express.js, Node.js, and Jade. The database that my team is using is MongoDB and holds the .json files that we parse in order to get the team names and point values to calculate the gamification scores.

Currently, we display the scores on a page when requested (i.e. if interested in a team's velocity, one can click on a button and the total points earned from sprints is displayed). However, we want our (javascript) queries to be more visual, with charts or graphs that can show trends over time.

This is my first time working with MongoDB, so I am unsure of what software can take the information gathered through the queries and provide a visual representation.

We are currently looking into MongoDB Charts, Appache Zeppelin, and Grafana, but we have the freedom to choose anything that is free/open-source and plays well with Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried MongoDB compass?

Comment: Hi Geza,

We saw MongoDB compass, but it looked like it would only let us visualize the raw data in our database and not the data after our queries.

Do you know of a way to run the schema analysis on an aggregation rather than the raw data?

Comment: I don't really think there's a tool for that... I would suggest exporting the data as JSON and then using some custom `map`ping and filtering in JS and visualising it with Google Charts. It's a bit of effort, but once it's done you can have a dashboard that updates by itself every time you open the page.

Comment: That sounds very useful. I'll see if we can figure that out.

Thank you!

Comment: I'll give you a bit of help: set up a GET endpoint in Node to go through each of the collections, and `find()` every document. Return this as a JSON in the format `{collection0: [/*...documents...*/], collection1: [/*...documents...*/], collection2: [/*...documents...*/]}` etc. On the front-end, get the data using `$.get()`, and go through them (using `Object.keys(array)` to get the names of all of the collections). Use `data.map()` to go through each item in each collection, and push each individual datapoint into an array of that properties values across all documents.